# installing Hellobar causing 501 method not implemented

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I've installed hellobar(https://www.hellobar.com) in my site
but after that some of requests like js images css,json outputs and ajax requests etc are showing **501 method not implemented error**

When I clear cookie its fine, at that particular time ajax etc is fine but when refreshed again **501 method not implemented error**

I am using codeigniter

hellobar installation is just adding a script before `</body>` tag

- How to solve this error?

Comment: This error should be very rare in any Web browser. It is more likely if the client is not a Web browser - particularly if the Web server is old. In either case if the client has specified a valid request type, then the Web server is either responding incorrectly or simply needs to be upgraded. [501 method not implemented](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E501.html)

Comment: is it due to cookie set by hellobar is not accepted by http request ?